# BitConverter VS ToString for Hex

Tags: c#, numbers, hex, endianness, bitconverter

Just wondering if someone could explain why the two following lines of code return "different" results? What causes the reversed values? Is this something to do with endianness?

```
int.MaxValue.ToString("X") //Result: 7FFFFFFF
BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(int.MaxValue)) //Result: FF-FF-FF-7F
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`int.MaxValue.ToString("X")` outputs `7FFFFFFF`, that is, the number `2147483647` *as a whole*.

On the other hand, `BitConverter.GetBytes` returns an array of bytes representing `2147483647` in memory. On your machine, this number is stored in little-endian (highest byte last). And `BitConverter.ToString` operates separately on each byte, therefore not reordering output to give the same as above, thus preserving the memory order.

However the two values are the same : `7F-FF-FF-FF` for `int.MaxValue`, in big-endian, and `FF-FF-FF-7F` for `BitConverter`, in little-endian. Same number.

Comment: Awesome detailed answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I would guess because `GetBytes` returns an array of bytes which `BitConverter.ToString` formatted - in my opinion - rather nicely

And also keep in mind that the bitwise represantattion may be different from the value! This depends where the most signigicant byte sits!

hth

Comment: yeah, sorry, I had only ony coffe till now. I updated my answer - binary represantation and value are/ may be different.