# How to guarantee to the specific endianness for hash computing?

Tags: c#

There is the function for sha256 computing:

```
static string GetHash(string input)
{
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);  //1

   SHA256 SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
   byte[] hashBytes =  SHA256.ComputeHash(bytes); //2

   var output = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes); //3
   return output;
}
```

It gets utf8-bytes from c# string, next it computes hash and returns one as string.

I'am confusing about BitConverter. Its `ToString(byte[])` method depends on machine architecture (liitle/big endian). My purpose is providing specific endianess (big-endian) for output string.

How can I do it?

I think it can be like:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input); //1
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(bytes)
}
//..
```

But I dont' know how `UTF8.GetBytes` works (UTF8.GetBytes docs doesn't contains anything about endianness). Is it depending on endianness also? If so I suppose it is right way to reverse array after 1 step, is it?

Comment: A method converting a `byte[]` to a hex `string` should not and can not depend on endianess, which is a property of multi-byte representations of data types. I believe the documentation for `BitConverter.ToString()` is technically inaccurate. The results will be different *if you've obtained that `byte` array from some other method that **is** dependent on endianess*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is it true UTF8.GetBytes represents c# string always as big-endian array? Then I could call Array.Reverse before 3 step.

Comment: **None** of `UTF8.GetBytes()`, `SHA256.ComputeHash()` or `BitConverter.ToString()` are dependent on the machine's endianess.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't matter here because UTF-8 is byte oriented as stated here : 
[Isn’t on big endian machines UTF-8's byte order different than on little endian machines? So why then doesn’t UTF-8 require a BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833693/isn-t-on-big-endian-machines-utf-8s-byte-order-different-than-on-little-endian)

Comment: I want to represent output sring as big-endian. There is [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107121/bitconverter-vs-tostring-for-hex)

Comment: @Mergasov - the difference in that question is because of the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` method call, not the `ToString()`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever am I right that the difference between `BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(...))` and `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(..))` is the first case depends on endianness and the second - not? Even if `BitConverter.ToString`, according doc, does? (as you say it is inaccurate)